# How would I put these multiple if statements into 1 if statement

Tags: python, python-2.x

Here is my code:

```
def winnerchecker():
    def player1win():
        print '\n' * 5, name, "YOU HAVE WON! GG TO", xplayer
        time.sleep(3)
        raise SystemExit()

    try:
        if "1,1" in turn1l and "1,2" in turn1l and "1,3"in turn1l:
            player1win()
        elif "1,1" in turn1l and "2,1" in turn1l and "3,1" in turn1l:
            player1win()
        elif "2,1" in turn1l and "2,2" in turn1l and "2,3" in turn1l:
            player1win()
        elif "3,1" in turn1l and "3,2" in turn1l and "3,3" in turn1l:
            player1win()
        elif "1,2" in turn1l and "2,2" in turn1l and "3,2" in turn1l:
            player1win()
        elif "1,3" in turn1l and "2,3" in turn1l and "3,3" in turn1l:
            player1win()
        elif "1,1" in turn1l and "2,2" in turn1l and "3,3" in turn1l:
            player1win()
    except NameError:
        pass
```

As you can see it is very long, is there anyway I could clean all this up into 1 if statement? Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Please tell us more about what you intend to accomplish with this code and what `turn1l` represents. We could mechanically transform this code, but it still wouldn't be good advice unless we understand your intentions. (See [ask].)

Answer (score 2):

My initial question is: What is `turn1l`? Is it a set? A list? A string? The following is based on `turn1l` being a set/list.

Write

```
checks = [
    # Vertical (or horizontal, depending on your datastructure)
    set(["1,1", "1,2", "1,3"]),
    set(["2,1", "2,2", "2,3"]),
    set(["3,1", "3,2", "3,3"]),
    # Horizontal (or vertical, depending on your datastructure)
    set(["1,1", "2,1", "3,1"]),
    set(["1,2", "2,2", "3,2"]),
    set(["1,3", "2,3", "3,3"]),
    # Diagonals
    set(["1,1", "2,2", "3,3"]),
    set(["3,1", "2,2", "1,3"]),
]
```

Then, write

```
def winnerchecker():
    def player1win():
        print '\n' * 5, name, "YOU HAVE WON! GG TO", xplayer
        time.sleep(3)
        raise SystemExit()

    try:
        for check in checks:
            if check.issubset(turn1l):
                player1win()
    except NameError:
        pass
```

Now, you don't need `player1win` as a separate function anymore. Inline it.

```
def winnerchecker():
    try:
        for check in checks:
            if check.issubset(turn1l):
                print '\n' * 5, name, "YOU HAVE WON! GG TO", xplayer
                time.sleep(3)
                raise SystemExit()
    except NameError:
        pass
```

Now there are a few more suggestions I'd like to make:

- Don't `raise SystemExit`. Prefer `os.exit()`, or better: write your code in such a way that the flow of control makes it stop, instead of having to call `os.exit`.
- Don't catch NameError. It will hide bugs: `name` might be undefined, `xplayer` might be undefined, `time` might be undefined (not imported), or `turn1l` might not be defined yet.
- Don't store strings in `turn1l`. Prefer tuples of ints. `(1, 3)` instead of `"1,3"`. Or, store the state as a matrix of cells instead of a list of player1-entries and player2-entries.

Judging by the above two facts, I think the code you have written can be cleaned up a lot more, but you have not supplied it. If you do (in another question, please!), I'd be happy to take a look at the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try using a loop to test for the x and y values. Something like:

```
for i in range(1, 4):
    if i ,1 in turn1l and i,2 in turn1l and i,3 in turn1l:
         player1Win();
    if 1, i in turn1l and 2, i in turn1l and 3,i in turn1l:
         player1Win();
if "1,1" in turn1l and "2,2" in turn1l and "3,3" in turn1l:
        player1win()
elif "3,1" in turn1l and "2,2" in turn1l and "1,3" in turn1l:
        player1win()
```

Forgive me, I don't know python, so this might be a little off, but the logic works. The for loop allows you to test for Horizontals and Verticals. Then you just need to add the diagonals. Good luck!

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Good job on your first answer.